# How to write attributes to the corresponding tags by using python? (the detailed example in the text body may help understand it better.)

Tags: python, list, attributes, tags

I'm struggling with how to write attributes for duplicated tags from a list. Below is an example of what I try to achieve:

```
a = [('tag1', 'attribute1'), ('tag2', 'attribute2'), ('tag2', 'attribute3'), ('tag5', 'attribute4'), ('tag5', 'attribute5'), ('tag5', 'attribute6')]
```

The result I want to have is:
 (same tag's attribute being written into the same tags.) 
`<tag1 attribute1=''>
<tag2 attribute2='' attribute3=''>
<tag5 attribute4='' attribute5='' attribute6=''>`

Right now I'm thinking about writing the tags into a list like below first:

```
tagList = []
for i in a:
    tagList.append(i[0])
unique = list(set(tagList))
```

so it returns `['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag5']`, but how do I match the attributes with the corresponding tags? Sorry, I'm new in Python, so still in the process of figuring many things out. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `defaultdict`. Then iterate over your list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

tags = defaultdict(set)
foo = [('tag1', 'attribute1'), ('tag2', 'attribute2'), ('tag2', 'attribute3'), ('tag5', 'attribute4'), ('tag5', 'attribute5'), ('tag5', 'attribute6')]

for tag, attribute in foo:
     tags[tag].add(attribute)
```

At this point you'll have a dictionary, where the keys are your tags, and your values are the set of unique attributes. Then you can iterate over the dictionary, to do whatever you want.

```
for tag, attributes in tags.iteritems():
    output = ["<", tag]
    for attribute in attributes:
        output.append(" {}=''".format(attribute))
    output.append(">")
    print("".join(output))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Batman, I tried your codes and they work great! I'm still trying to figure out how to write them into the format I want. But this is very useful! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you your output to look like, so I've edited to code to just print the strings.

Comment: Thank you! Yea I'll need to adjust the output format. Will try it tomorrow and get back to you by then! :)

Comment: Hey @batman, I got an error message saying that `AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`, seems like `iteritems` is not recognized..

Comment: Ah i think I got it! I should use `tags.items()` rather than `iteritems()`, as I'm using python3.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, I meant to mention that. Wasn't sure which version you were using.